# Why doesn't justify-content: center work in IE?

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

[I have this simple div with a button inside of it](https://jsfiddle.net/gk32ezgg/). `justify-content: center;` works fine using Firefox and Chrome, but does not work on IE 11:

```css
#div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="button">HELLO</button>
</div>
```

My goal is that, when I use `transform` with `rotate(90deg)` or `rotate(270deg)`, [the button will fit into the div](https://jsfiddle.net/gk32ezgg/1/):

```css
#div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="button">HELLO</button>
</div>
```

The `height` and `width` of the `div` and `button` are always the same, but are customizable.

As much as possible, I prefer not wrapping elements.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

IE11 needs the parent to have `flex-direction: column`.

This example has your button rotated:

```css
#div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column
}
#button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="button">HELLO</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought flex-direction assigned the main axis for the parent.  So if it's set to row, `justify-content:center` should center content along the horizontal axis.  If you explicitly set it to column, it should center content along the vertical.  IE11 doesn't appear to respect `justify-content:center` on a row.

Comment: For my case, I use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` All depends on your requirements :)

Answer (score 6):

In my case I had to make the flex container's height 100%. justify-content worked without a problem after that.

I also had to make the (first level) children's max-width 100% to fix some content overflowing horizontally.