# Flex item not centering in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to position a small box in the center of the page on both axes. I got it working in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but IE still misaligns. The box seems stuck in the bottom right corner of what appears a virtual box scaled 200% compared to my content.

[image]

I tried changing flex attributes of `.content` and wrapping it into another `<div />` but to no avail.

How can I get the box centered in IE?

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
```

Comment: IE11? Because as [Can i use](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) says : _Partial support is due to large amount of bugs presen_

Comment: Yes, IE11. I wonder if there's any workaroud.

Comment: try to add to your .content `margin: auto`

Comment: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270465/why-doesnt-justify-content-center-work-in-ie) on SO, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

Absolutely-positioned children of a flex container are taken out of the normal flow of the document.

In fact, they are not even flex items, because they don't accept flex properties.

*from the spec:*

> [§ 4.1. Absolutely-positioned Flex Children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)
>
> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex
>   container does not participate in flex layout.

Here is why your layout works anyway in Chrome, Firefox and Edge:

*continuing with the spec:*

> The static position of an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container is determined such that the child is positioned as if it were the sole flex item in the flex container, assuming both the child and the flex container were fixed-size boxes of their used size. For this purpose, `auto` margins are treated as zero.
>
> *[read more >>](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)*

However, [IE11 provides only partial support](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for the [current flexbox specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), which may explain the rendering difference.

### Solution

Since your content item isn't doing anything flex-related, just use a standard, non-flex method for horizontal and vertical centering.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
```

The centering method above is explained here:

- [Element will not stay centered, especially when re-sizing screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36817249/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the position property. Code as below:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

The result in IE browser like this:

[image]